# Batch load data really large in dataflow insert to Big Query Step

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

Running into an issue with Dataflow I am hoping to fix. Basically the pipeline runs correctly if streaming data continually however if I drop a number of files together I am running into an issue where the data is not loaded to bq and I am seeing 100's of GB in the batchloads substep of the bigquery loads step

[image]

```
            validCollection = validCollection.apply("Specify Window",
                    Window.<SData>into(FixedWindows.of(Duration.standardMinutes(5)))

                            .triggering(Repeatedly.forever(AfterProcessingTime.pastFirstElementInPane()))
                            .discardingFiredPanes() 
                            .withAllowedLateness(Duration.standardDays(1))
```

This is the code I have above. I am wondering can someone point me in the direction of why the above is not emitting data to bq for hours at a time? I think it is something to do with my triggering and I need to have a time trigger or something but my understanding is that this could result in dataloss as bundles are not accepted after the fact (totally open to correction on that)

Thanks very much in advance

Comment: Have you found something interesting in Logs?

Comment: This is an interesting question. Have you found anything in log about BQ insert rate limit. etc.?

Comment: So you're question is a bit confusing? Are you writing to BQ or reading from? Because the code you are showing is for reading whereas it seems the issue you are having is inserting data into BQ. Are you using [FILE_LOADS]( https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.19.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/bigquery/BigQueryIO.Write.Method.html#FILE_LOADS) to upload the data? And if so, what is the [triggering frequency](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.19.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/bigquery/BigQueryIO.Write.html#withTriggeringFrequency-org.joda.time.Duration-) that you are setting?